# Late answer or first post?

Tags: discussion, support, bug

I reviewed [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20059/is-spoofing-a-ca-signed-certificate-possible/82479#82479) answer just right now. The question was asked 2 years ago. So the answer must be qualified as a **Late answer**, however I got it in **First posts** category. Why is this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it is a first post as well.  Depending on which review queues you qualify for and check first, you may see it in both.

Comment: Thank you. But it appeared only on the **First posts** queue.

Comment: It depends how you open queues. I tend to open them all at once in different tabs, and work through them one at a time. Which means by the time I get to the last queue some will have already come up in previous queues. If I open queues one at a time, they won't come up in the other queues

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you mean.

Comment: In an extreme case, you could get a single post showing up in "low quality posts", "first posts", and either "late answers" or "close votes".  In general, you only get to review a post once despite it appearing in multiple queues.